# Matplotlib - legend not showing element names

Tags: matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I am having problems in making the legend shows its element names: male and female.
My data has 3 columns: sex, height, and weight. I want to make a scatter plot showing the relation between weight versus height, but also illustrate if a data point represents a female or a male.
Everything works well, but the legend. It only shows an empty square (click the link to see [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArFuA.png)).
Please let me know how can I fix this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = "C:\\height_weight.csv
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

m = df["sex"] == 1
plt.scatter(df2.loc[m, "height"], df2.loc[m, "weight"], c= "#16c6f7", s=1)
plt.scatter(df2.loc[~m, "height"], df2.loc[~m, "weight"], c= "#ff8b87", s=1)
plt.xlabel("Height")
plt.ylabel("Weight")
plt.legend(loc=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to add a `label` to your scatter commands:

```py
plt.scatter(..., label='male')
```